# Splitting and appending a string in python

Tags: python, string

I have these strings that look like this:

```
'Census Tract 201, Autauga County, Alabama: Summary level: 140, state:01> county:001> tract:020100'
```

I want to take the state number 01 the county number 001 and the tract 020100 and make a new string 01001020100. How do I achieve this in Python?

All of these strings are in a pandas dataframe so I need to apply this method across all of the rows. There are all of type string as of I said above.

To provide more context here is all my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

df = pd.read_csv('all_data.csv')

df = pd.read_csv('all_data.csv')

column_of_interest = df['Location+Type']

column_of_interest.head()

print(type(column_of_interest[0][0]))

<class 'str'>

find_census = lambda text: text.split('state:')[1].split('>')[0] + text.split('county:')[1].split('>')[0] + text.split('tract:')[1].split('>')[0]
column_of_interest['GEOID'] = column_of_interest.apply(lambda x: find_census(x['Location+Type']))
```

and I am getting this error for the lambda:

```
     1 find_census = lambda text: text.split('state:')[1].split('>')[0] + text.split('county:')[1].split('>')[0] + text.split('tract:')[1].split('>')[0]
----> 2 column_of_interest['GEOID'] = column_of_interest.apply(lambda x: find_census(x['Location+Type']))

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: What data type/format is this? Can you include some more context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal, you can use a regular expression syntax. But, It seems you are a beginner, so I come here with a basic logic based on `split` method. Here is the code:

```
census = 'Census Tract 201, Autauga County, Alabama: Summary level: 140, state:01> county:001> tract:020100'

state = census.split('state:')[1].split('>')[0]
county = census.split('county:')[1].split('>')[0]
tract = census.split('tract:')[1].split('>')[0]
result = state + county + tract

print(result) # 01001020100
```

> **Update:** using *lambda expression* to generate the desired outputs

```
find_census = lambda text: text.split('state:')[1].split('>')[0] + text.split('county:')[1].split('>')[0] + text.split('tract:')[1].split('>')[0]

# to use the above lambda expression
print(find_census(census)) # 01001020100
```

Comment: do you know how to put your code into a lambda expression. I tried but my code states that 
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Update: I add the *lambda expression* synthax in the code.

Comment: Sorry I am a newb but I am trying to do what you did on an entire dataframe like this:find_census = lambda text: text.split('state:')[1].split('>')[0] + text.split('county:')[1].split('>')[0] + text.split('tract:')[1].split('>')[0]
column_of_interest['GEOID'] = column_of_interest.apply(lambda x: find_census(x['Location+Type']))

Comment: and I am getting this still:  TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: You can update your code with more details about the variables and the code you are working on..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text follows the pattern you have given
you can use regular expressions to get the result.

Here `\d` corresponds to extracting a number
     `\s` is a blank space

```
s = 'Census Tract 201, Autauga County, Alabama: Summary level: 140, state:01> county:001> tract:020100'
import re
m=re.search("state:(\d+)>\scounty:(\d+)>\stract:(\d+)",s)
''.join(m.groups())
```

Output

```
'01001020100'
```

Comment: I am trying to use your code in a lambda function. I have a pandas dataframe with all of those strings "s". And I tried this: column_of_interest['GEOID'] = column_of_interest.apply(lambda x: re.search("state:(\d+)>\scounty:(\d+)>\stract:(\d+)", x['Location+Type']))

Comment: But I am getting this error: TypeError: string indices must be integers